# Pairs of opposite values

Tags: php, arrays, function

I need to write a function that when i have an array with n numbers from -10 to 10 (without 0) returns quantity of pairs from the array which sum gives 0.

For example:
$input = array (**3**, 6, **-3**, 5, **-10**, 3, **10**, **1**, **7**, **-1**, -9, -8, **7**, 7, **-7**, -2, **-7**);

In example right answer is 5 (pairs are bolded)

i figure out something like that:

```
<?php

$array = [3, 6, -3, 5, -10, 3, 10, 1, 7, -1, -9, -8, 7, 7, -7, -2, -7];

function pairs($array=[]){
$copy = $array;

$arrayLength = count($copy);

$pairs=0;
while($arrayLength!=0){
    $a = array_values($array)[0];
    $b = -$a;

    for( $i=1 ; $i==$arrayLength ; $i++ ){

        if($array[$i]==$b){
            unset($array[$i]);
            $pairs++;
            $arrayLength--;
        }
        else{
            unset($array[$i]);
            $arrayLength--;
        }
    }
return $pairs;
}
unset($copy);


}
var_dump(pairs($array));
?>
```

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: do you want to get an array of pairs? or do you want to sum of actual array? BTW: answer is `2` not `5` `(6+5+3+7-9-8-2) = 2`

Comment: @Marc B; His problem is that it does not work. For anyone else looking into it: https://3v4l.org/JlvPM

Comment: no its actually 5 - like ( 3+ (-3) = 0), my problem is i cant get into for loop and i don`t know what i get wrong ;/

Comment: Mubin You misunderstand the problem; he is looking for pairs that when added together give 0. I think he is still wrong though as depending on how he wants it answered the values can be flipped(3+-3 = 0, -3+3 = 0) so really its 10, perhaps @Konrad Coner can confirm.

Comment: @NeilMasters: you misunderstood too, lol, actually he want to calculate total number of pairs

Comment: @NeilMasters: check answer with demo, and look at demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
function pairs($array=[]){
    $pairs = [];
    // counting the positive and negative of each number in the set
    foreach($array as $v){
        $av = abs($v);
        if(!isset($pairs[$av]))
            $pairs[$av] = [
                'pos' => 0,
                'neg' => 0
            ];

        ($v > 0) ? $pairs[$av]['pos']++ :  $pairs[$av]['neg']++;
    }

    $pair_count = 0;
    // getting the number of pairs for each number, based on those counts
    foreach($pairs as $pair){
        $pair_count += min($pair['pos'],$pair['neg']);
    }
    return $pair_count;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pCwGNK)**

This gets rid of the annoying need to rebuild the array indexes every time you unset (part of where your issues with your provided function are coming from), and also makes it so you only need to loop through it twice and therefore is more efficient, especially for large data sets.

Comment: That`s ok, thank you very much